# How to change the page and change only one component, not the entire html

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm starting in React and I'm curious about about if have any way to change a page without reload all the html, changing only a content component for example.
I know that there is a way to change the component without change the url but I thought that if the url change too the application would be better.

Comment: That's what `react-router` allows you to do, client side routing: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router

Comment: react-router v4 is your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [React Router is the exact thing you're looking for](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/)

Here, how you can achieve what you're looking for.

First, wrap your app with `BrowserRouter`

```
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import React from 'react';
class App extends React.Component {
  return (){
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
             <SomeComponent />
        </BrowserRouter>
     )
  }
}
```

---

Now just use the `Route` and `Link`. Route told the application which component to render on the basis of the current route and Link changes the URL without reloading the whole page

```
import { Route, Link, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import React from 'react';
import {Circle, Square} from './someFileWithComponents';

class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
   render(){
     return (
       <div>
          <Link to='/circle' >Circle</Link>
          <Link to='/square' >Square</Link>

          <Switch>
             <Route path='/circle' component={Circle} />
             <Route path='/square' component={Square} />
          </Switch>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**React Router is what you looking for**

```js
   

  const AppRouter =()=>(
        <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
        
        <Header/>//where Header components contains the navigation
        <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={BookListPage} exact={true} />
        <Route path="/create" component={AddBookItem} />
        <Route path="/edit/:id" component={EditBookItem} />
        <Route path="/help" component={HelpPage} />
        <Route component={NotFoundPage} /> 
        </Switch>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
  

  export default AppRouter;
```